# Forward Thinking Systems: spam or not?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, spam

This question has a few particularities that might be interpreted as signs of spam:
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11467

- Both asker and answerer have created their Software Recommendations account the same day.
- The same day they created their account, one asked and the other answered 17 minutes later.
- The asker has no rep on any other site.
- The question is very unclear (does not even tell what hardware is embedded in vehicles), but somehow, asker and answerer seem to understand each other very well.
- Answerer has awarded nearly all of his rep as a bounty to the question he answered, which is highly unusual, it might be because he is 100% sure to get awarded the bounty.

Am I too suspicious? Could it be spam? Do we have any way to know anyway? What should we do?

Comment: To me looks like a "deal-maker". Note the answer to the comment on the question itself: Asked for details on his requirements, and where he gets the data from, OP answers *We got an online demo from the company below*. So I tend to agree on your suspicion, sounds like a "you place an ad – we give you a discount" campaign. As for the bounty: IMHO You cannot collect a bounty you've set yourself (they might have missed that fact).

Comment: PS: Funny thing is, neither question nor answer specify explicitly what OS is supported (OK, answer says between the lines it somehow interacts with Android tablets).

Comment: I recommend flag one of the posts in the future and explain all that to a moderator. No need to discuss this in public.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a sockpuppet to me. I've deleted the question, suspended and warned the parent user, and destroyed the sock puppet. The bounty was a 'very' nice touch, if not for the fact that it was very suspicious.

While full disclosure is necessary, it isn't sufficient sometimes.

Nice catch ;)

Comment: Looks like the end of your third sentence is missing?

Comment: Sorta fixed. This was a *pretty* unusual case and I got distracted ;p.